# Finding common partial strings between 2 datasets in R

Tags: r

I have two datasets - One with a list of 1 million companies, another with 15,000. I need to find companies common to both of these.
The problem is that the names are not exactly same, thus I need to do partial matching.
For example: In database 1: ABC Industries, In database 2: ABC. Can I match these two rows using R?

P.S. - I am a beginner to R but willing to learn quickly.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  I edited your question to change 10 lakh to 1 million because most people outside of India won't understand what a lakh is.  Anyway, apart from that please provide a minimal reproducible example dataset that we can use to help you.

Answer (score 0):

```r
# short names
short <- c("ABC", "BCA")
# long names
long <- c("ABC industry", "TATA consultancy", "BFH printing", "HMC BCA", "ABC", "BCA corporation")

# using grep to find short names in long names column
long[grep(paste0(short, collapse = "|"), long)]
#> [1] "ABC industry"    "HMC BCA"         "ABC"             "BCA corporation"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>